# Golang best practice to access shared connection resources?

Tags: go

What is the best practice for handling scope with dealing with shared connection resources to outside services in golang (RabbitMQ, database, etc)? For example, given this code using database/sql, pq, and http:

```
func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "user=root dbname=root")
        if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    http.HandleFunc("/", front_handler)
    http.HandleFunc("/get", get_handler)
    http.HandleFunc("/set", set_handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

What's the best way to make the `db` object available to my registered handlers?

Do I put the `db` declaration outside the main scope (this would cause me unit testing problems in Python but might be okay here)?

Do I put the handler declarations inside the main scope (it doesn't seem like I'm allowed to nest functions)?

Is there an addressing scheme I can use to access the main scope (I'd do something like that in puppet)?

Some other option?

Comment: You need to declare db outside of main.

Comment: Will this cause my any issues with unit testing? I haven't done much with the testing framework yet, in Python I pull things in as a from/include with unittest but I doubt it's like that here.

Comment: I don't see how it would be a problem in testing. Plus, you can't do *anything* with a `db` that only exists in main, so you either declare it at the package scope, or you create a context and pass that around to all handlers.

Comment: Works for me, I'll look at contexts as well. Thanks much!

Comment: FYI, the most common package for context handling is [x/net/context](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/context), but I would put that off until you know you need it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of ways you could deal with this. Firstly, having opened the connection in this scope, you probably want to defer it's close here.

```
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "user=root dbname=root")
        if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
defer db.Close()
```

Which will ensure the connection gets cleaned up when you're leaving this scope. Regarding your handlers... It would be simple to write them as closures in the same scope as the connection so you can use it freely.

EDIT: To clarify, you said you don't think you can nest functions in main. You can do this with something like;

```
get_handler := func() {
      return db.ReadTheData()
}
http.HandleFunc("get", get_handler)
```

Comment: Yeah I'm missing the defer in the example since it was a quick 'put an example' together however I'm still not getting how I could access the 'db' object from main_handler, get_handler, set_handler. Trying to access 'db' from any of those functions just comes up with 'undefined: db'. I could do a closure in the scope but I feel like there has to be a way people are doing this where it's accessible from a function (perhaps included from another file). I suppose I could pass a pointer to the object through if I had to, I'm still iffy on what namespace tomfoolery I can do in golang.

Comment: @RyanM yeah the other option would be to pass a reference to it into the scope where the handlers are defined. Yet another option would be to open the connection in that scope. If you just declare it in the main package, outside of the method I believe it will give it a global scope.

Comment: Will doing that (ie declaring in the global scope) cause any issues with unit tests? I haven't tinkered with the testing framework yet.

Comment: @RyanM I don't think it will be an issue but I can't guarantee that for lack of personal experience.

Comment: Others seem to think it'll work okay, or that I could use contexts to get around this. I think I'm good to go.

Answer (score 0):

It's common for most apps to start out with the DB handler at the global scope. `sql.DB` is defined to be safe for concurrent access, and therefor can be simultaneously used by all handlers that need it.

```
var db *sql.DB

func main() {
    var err error
    db, err = sql.Open("postgres", "user=root dbname=root")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
...
```

Comment: So I can just create a global sql.DB type variable and load the actual db object data in it later? Nice, thanks.

Comment: @RyanM: You're actually only creating the `db` variable of type `*sql.DB`, there is no pointer yet, and the value is `nil` until you assign something. It's sort of a semantic difference, but it's important to understand.

Comment: Yeah I misspoke originally, editing the comment afterwards once I got my head wrapped around what was happening.